# Height:100% doesn't work for border

Tags: html, css

I have created a master page in asp.net which uses the following css to create my border. I have a logon screen which is centred in the middle of the browser window depending upon its size using the css (accountinfo). See browser screenprint below.

As you can see the border doesnt stretch to the bottom of the browser, is there a way of achieving this? I have tried height:100% in my body and .page however it makes no difference.

```
body{
background-color: #EFEFEF;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
padding: 0;
position: relative;    
}

.page{
margin:10px;
background-color: #fff;
border:2px solid #fff;
border-radius:25px;
-moz-border-radius:25px;
height:1000px;
}

.accountInfo{
 position: fixed;
 top: 50%;
 left: 50%;
 margin-top: -50px;
 margin-left: -100px;
 width:200px;
 height:100px;
 font-size:80%;
 }
```

[image]

Comment: Please put it in jsFiddle so we can play with it...

Comment: @Michael Easter I have two pages (master page and logon page) so i have merged them into one since im new to this jsfiddle. Even before i entered the logon code, the border went straight to the bottom of the result window... I'm now abit confused. Please see link: http://jsfiddle.net/4DEBp/

Comment: @Michael Easter, i also removed the css link since i summed it wasnt needed for jsfiddle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not

```
position: fixed;
z-index -1;
left:20px;
right:20px;
top:20px;
bottom:20px;
```

You could also add height:100% to `<html>` and `<body>` elements

#### edit

also to the `<form>` element